# Execute (open) a view from another view in eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a Eclipse plug-in which has a view. This view has a hyperlink whose action has to execute (open) another view. Could I know the line code I should fit to open (fire) a view in the handler of hyperlink.
Could anybody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("myViewID");
```